# Programmatically create header file

Tags: programming-practices, c

What's the best way to programmatically create a header file for another project?

Here's the specific use case: one program fingerprints the device for discrete information like version number, id string, etc, and then creates a header file populating static structs/program constants. This header file is then consumed by multiple projects to define a type of that class.

I thought about reading writing in an xml or flat file, that means consuming projects need to know that structure of the and plug in libraries to read it.

Comment: I think this is better suited for SO.

Comment: This question is fine here: Programmmers.SE is about write-boarding ideas. There's nothing about this question that involves getting into code.

Comment: These things can be done with a macro language like [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) which is very well suited to generate files from templates.

Answer (score 2):

If you're building on *NIX (Unix, Linux, or OSX), a common approach is to have a make rule that converts a .h.in to .h using sed (or perl). The implementation would vary on Windows, but what you should be aiming at is

project.h.in:

```
#define VERSION __VERSION__
#define COPYRIGHT __COPYRIGHT__
#define SOMETHING_ELSE __SOMETHING_ELSE__
```

Your fingerprinting tool (or a wrapper around it) then does simple text replacement, so you end up with

```
#define VERSION 2.3.4
#define COPYRIGHT "(C) 2011 Stack Overflow"
#define SOMETHING_ELSE "A bucket of fish"
```

You could use Ant to do replacements (although Ant isn't really the right tool for C programming)

Depending on what exactly you're fingerprinting, [automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/)/[autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) might be worth investigating - on Windows you may need to run these under  [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Using a template like this means you can leave any header comments, macro definitions, etc. in the header template.

Comment: They often use `m4` for this.  It has a learning curve, but works out well in the long run.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)

Comment: m4 is usually used to generate code that then uses sed to create the macros, actually.

Comment: Thanks, that's something like I was angling towards. The project is to poll a usb device, and produce a set of pre-populated #defs and structs which describe the device (e.g. hw id, transfer rate, etc) in a single file. You can then include that file in any number of projects, e.g. in Teensy usb programming projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) infrastructure would deal with included headers. Consider using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) (or [ninja](https://ninja-build.com/), etc...). If your C compiler is [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)), notice the [`-M` and related compiler flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options). You might also want to use [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) and/or [precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) to speed up incremental build time. But read [*Recursive make considered harmful*](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) and consider other build automation tools, perhaps even [omake](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/omake.html) or [scons](https://scons.org/).

Your `Makefile` could contain [`-include` directives](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html#Include). With `ninja`, your `build.ninja` file is usually generated (e.g. by some ad-hoc [Python](https://python.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script, by [cmake](https://cmake.org/) or [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/), etc...), etc...

Both [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) and [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) are generating more and more of their own header files (in Bismon: C files; in RefPerSys: C++ files). But so do [s48](https://s48.org/), [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/?s=CAIA) (see [this](https://www.yseop.com/articles/seminar-jacques-pitrat-father-symbolic-ai), old tarball [here](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/caia-su-24feb2016.tar.bz2)), and [Chicken/Scheme](https://www.call-cc.org/).